# Create DB table from JSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

This is my first time with SQL Server 2016. I would like to know how to create a db table from json like:

```
{ "column1":"int","column2":"varchar(255)","column3":"column3Type..." }
```

It is important to me to use JSON, cause I would like to create generic tables, which has many different columns.

I don't want to use Mongo or other document-oriented database.

What you advise in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build  create table statement.
Simply:

- replace '":"' with space
- replace '","' with ', '
- replace '{' with
  'Create table tbl_name ('
- replace '}' with ')'